# Need help debugging code for echelon form matrix function

Tags: matlab, function, linear-algebra

In MATLAB: Having trouble debugging code for a function that reduces a matrix to echelon form.

I tried the following matrix:
A=[1 2 3 ;1 2 4; 1 2 4; 1 2 4]
 and gives me the same result after trying multiple ways to fix it:
A =

```
 1     2     3
 0     0     1
 0     0     1
 0     0     1
```

```matlab
A=[1 2 3 ;1 2 4; 1 2 4; 1 2 4]
echelon(A)
function x = echelon(A)
[m,n]= size(A);%m=rows, n= columns
j=1;
i=1;
   while (i<=m && j<=n )
       if is_pivot(A,i,j)==true 
           for k=i+1:m
            if A(i,j)~=0
              A(k,:)=A(k,:)-((A(k,j)/A(i,j))*A(i,:));%zero out corresponding row        
       else 
            C = A(i,:); %Let C be the ith first row of the matrix
            A(i,:)= A(k,:);%Exchange the row with the one below it
            A(k,:) = C;
          end
          end
            if A(i,j)~=0
              A(k,:)=A(k,:)-((A(k,j)/A(i,j))*A(i,:));%zero out corresponding row
            end 
       end           
       if ~all(A(i,:)==0)
          i=i+1;
          j=j+1;
       end
       if i==m &&  all(A(i,:)==0)
           break;
       end
       A
   end
end
```

The matrix should be reduced to:

```
1     2     3
0     0     1
0     0     0
0     0     0
```

The is_pivot function is the following

```
%is_pivot function checks to see if value is a pivot
%user gives A the matrix, i =row, j=column
function x= is_pivot2(A,i,j)
   x=false;
   idx = 1:size(A, 2) < j;
   if all(A(i,:)==0)
       x=false;
   elseif  all(A(:,j)==0)
       x=false;
   elseif j==1 && A(i,j)~=0
       x=true;   
   elseif all(A(i, idx) == 0) 
      x=true;
   end
x
end
```

Comment: the function `is_pivot()` seems custom. can you post that too?

Comment: yep, just posted it above as well

Comment: The first thing you should do for easier debugging is using proper indenting. It is hard to follow the code logic when indenting is misleading.

Comment: Does the pivot function have all the correct if statements? I tried to debug for a few hours , still unsure what the issue could be. The code stops when there is a repeat of rows, as the example shows.